# Powershell keeps asking me the same question

Tags: windows, powershell

I'm trying to remove a security group from a list of systems that I choose (unless I can remove a certain group from an entire OU in AD.)

however I keep getting the following message for every system:

```
Remove members from group
Do you want to remove all the specified member(s) from the specified group(s)?
[Y] Yes  [A] Yes to All  [N] No  [L] No to All  [S] Suspend  [?] Help (default is "Y"):
```

This is my code:

```
Import-Module ActiveDirectory 
$comps=Get-Content "C:\nice\LIST-OF-SYSTEMS.txt"


foreach ($comp in $comps) {
  $dns = get-adcomputer $comp
  $b = $dns.distinguishedname
  Remove-ADPrincipalGroupMembership $b EXAMPLE_GROUP
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When in doubt, read the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/addsadministration/remove-adprincipalgroupmembership).

> ### Notes
>
> - This cmdlet does not work with an Active Directory snapshot.
> - This cmdlet does not work with a read-only domain controller.
> - **By default, this cmdlet has the *Confirm* parameter set, which prompts you to confirm before a removal of the specified object type can occur. To bypass prompting for confirmation before removal, you can specify `-Confirm:$False` when using this cmdlet.**

Emphasis mine.

Comment: I feel dumb. but THANK YOU!!

Answer (score 2):

You need to add the `-confirm` switch on your `Remove-ADPrincipalGroupMembership` cmdlet and tell it to be false, that way you tell your command not to ask you to confirm each time it is run.

```
Import-Module ActiveDirectory$comps = Get-Content "C:\nice\LIST-OF-SYSTEMS.txt"
foreach ($comp in $comps)
{
    $dns = get-adcomputer $comp
    $b = $dns.distinguishedname
    Remove-ADPrincipalGroupMembership $b EXAMPLE_GROUP -Confirm:$false
}
```